# Problem with GIT pull overriding previous code

Tags: git, version-control, github

I am new to GIT and face scenario as follow:

push file below:

index.php

```
$name = "steve";

echo("good morning");
echo($name);
```

pull the file and then **remove the $name variable** by accidentally.

```
echo("good morning");
echo($name);
```

Without realizing it,  pull and push the new code to server. Problem is the code is broke and no longer working, GIT won't prompt for removal of the line. Is there anyway to solve such scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to handle this, Git would need to have a knowledge of the content that you're pusing. In your case, Git would have to know that removing `$name = "steve";` in a `.php` file would produce an error.

But this could be perfectly fine for plain `.txt` file where you're just writing text.

Not the `pull` overrides the previous code but *you* did. You removed the line, you told Git to commit that version, you pulled that version from the remote repo. And all that went good.

The best way to *solve* such a scenario is *avoiding* it by **testing** your code before pushing.

---

If that scenario occurs in spite of careful testing, you could of course use Git to restore the last version that was checked in and working using

```
git checkout <SHA-HASH> -- index.php
```

where `<SHA-HASH>` is the commit-ID of the last good version of `index.php`.

Comment: Is there anyway to instruct GIT to prompt for manual review for line deletion, just like the file with line conflict? Because, it would be too easy to break the code, was curious to know best practice on how to maintain integrity without throw lots of test script.

Comment: @TonyMocha: no, there isn't. Like in every other VCS too.

Comment: Deleting lines is a perfectly normal part of software maintenance.  A VCS that warned about it would be nearly unusable.

Comment: I am new to VCS thingy, guess I know it better now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to be aware of what you're changing.  In git, this means using

```
git diff
```

to check what code has changed before you add a file to the index.  You can also use `gitk` to look at your changes.  They'll show up as a red dot marked "Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index."

If the problem comes from adding a whole file to the index, when you only want *some* of the changes to go in, here's a method you can use to add individual chunks of code:

```
git add -p
```

This will go through the various changed bits of code and ask you, for each one, whether to add it to the index or not.  So if you have some changes in a file that need to be checked in, while others are just for experimentation or debugging, you can use `git add -p` to add only the ones that should really be checked in.